# Sorting an array of objects by multiple criteria with null values

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Alright, so I have an array of objects that includes null values for a certain property.

The object looks roughly like this for sorting purposes... (40 elements, but this will suffice...).

It needs to be sorted based on `roulette` descending (with `roulette` sometimes being null), then `novelty`, then `popularity`.

My head is getting a bit crushed.

This works to sort the `roulette` in descending, but how do I need to extend it to include the other two criteria?

Object:

```
[
 {
  title: 'one',
  popularity: 4,
  novelty: 3
 },
 {
  title: 'two',
  popularity: 1
  novelty: 4
 },
 {
  title: 'three',
  popularity: 5,
  novelty: 3,
  roulette: 0
 },
 {
  title: 'four',
  popularity: 5,
  novelty: 3,
  roulette: 1
 }
]
```

Partially working function:

```
  object.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a['roulette'] == null) return 1
    if (b['roulette'] == null) return -1
    if (a['roulette'] === b['roulette']) return 0
    return b.roulette > a.roulette ? 1 : -1
  });
```

Comment: please add some more data and the wanted result. i am sorry i can not read what novelty means in sorting.

Comment: @NinaScholz novelty is an attrbute in his json.

Comment: yes, i read this, but where should `null` go?

Comment: @NinaScholz according to his partial sort function null values will come at bottom.

Comment: are there `null` values in roulette or is roulette just not set?

Comment: Roulette is sonetimes not set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An attempt with sorting with priority and groups.

```js
var data = [{ title: 'one', popularity: 4, novelty: 3 }, { title: 'two', popularity: 1, novelty: 4 }, { title: 'three', popularity: 5, novelty: 3, roulette: 0 }, { title: 'four', popularity: 5, novelty: 3, roulette: 1 }, { title: 'five', popularity: 5, novelty: 4, roulette: null }, { title: 'six', popularity: 5, novelty: 5, roulette: undefined }];

data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (
        (a.roulette === undefined || a.roulette === null) - (b.roulette === undefined || b.roulette === null) ||
        a.roulette - b.roulette ||
        a.novelty - b.novelty ||
        a.popularity - b.popularity
    );       
});

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `b`s be on the left? Otherwise, that's a pretty slick solution.

Comment: Both `'roulette' in {roulette:null}` and `'roulette' in {roulette:undefined}` are true so those will always come out true unless `roulette` hasn't been set at all.

Comment: it not clear from the data, if it is set with `null` or `undefined`, not at all inside of the object.

Comment: This is like...  99.9% there. There is a minor side effect for the first undefined/null data point, but it's minor enough for me not to care.

I needed biggest on top, so slight mod:

    return (
        (a.roulette === undefined || a.roulette === null) - (b.roulette === undefined || b.roulette === null) ||
        b.roulette - a.roulette ||
        b.novelty - a.novelty ||
        b.popularity - a.popularity
    );

Answer (score 1):

Here is the preferential sorting (descending) with `roulette`, `novelty` and `popularity` (in that order)

This handles *both* `null` and `undefined` - check out the demo below:

```js
var object=[{title:"one",popularity:4,novelty:3},{title:"two",popularity:1,novelty:4},{title:"three",popularity:5,novelty:3,roulette:0},{title:"four",popularity:5,novelty:3,roulette:1},{title:"five",roulette:4,novelty:null},{title:"six",popuplarity:7},{title:"seven",novelty:8,roulette:null},{title:"eight",novelty:0},{title:"nine",popularity:10}];

function ifNumber(num) {
  if(num == undefined || num == null)
    return -Infinity;
  else
    return num;
}

var result = object.sort(function(a, b) {
  return (ifNumber(b.roulette) - ifNumber(a.roulette)) 
      || (ifNumber(b.novelty) - ifNumber(a.novelty))
      || (ifNumber(b.popuplarity) - ifNumber(a.popuplarity));
});
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try sorting based on weighted rank:

```js
var data=[{title:"one",popularity:4,novelty:3},{title:"two",popularity:1,novelty:4},{title:"three",popularity:5,novelty:3,roulette:0},{title:"four",popularity:5,novelty:3,roulette:1}];

data.sort(function(a, b) {
  var r1 = a.roulette === undefined ? -1 : a.roulette;
  var r2 = b.roulette === undefined ? -1 : b.roulette;
  var n1 = a.novelty === undefined ? -1 : a.novelty;
  var n2 = b.novelty === undefined ? -1 : b.novelty;
  var p1 = a.popularity === undefined ? -1 : a.popularity;
  var p2 = b.popularity === undefined ? -1 : b.popularity;

  var r_rank = r1 > r2 ? -100 : r1 < r2 ? 100 : 0;
  var n_rank = n1 > n2 ? -10 : n1 < n2 ? 10 : 0;
  var p_rank = p1 > p2 ? -1 : p1 < p2 ? 1 : 0;

  return r_rank + n_rank + p_rank;
})

var r_rank = r1 > r2 ? -100 : r1 < r2 ? 100 : 0;
var n_rank = n1 > n2 ? -10 : n1 < n2 ? 10 : 0;
var p_rank = p1 > p2 ? -1 : p1 < p2 ? 1 : 0;
return r_rank + n_rank + p_rank;
})

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just include more conditionals:

```js
var data = [{"title":"one","popularity":4,"novelty":3},{"title":"two","popularity":1,"novelty":4},{"title":"three","popularity":5,"novelty":3,"roulette":0},{"title":"four","popularity":5,"novelty":3,"roulette":1}];
data.sort(function(a,b) {
  if (a.roulette < b.roulette || a.roulette == null) return +1;
  if (a.roulette > b.roulette || b.roulette == null) return -1;
  if (a.novelty < b.novelty || a.novelty == null) return +1;
  if (a.novelty > b.novelty || b.novelty == null) return -1;
  if (a.popularity < b.popularity || a.popularity == null) return +1;
  if (a.popularity > b.popularity || b.popularity == null) return -1;
  return 0;
})
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Maybe something like `a.roulette < b.roulette || a.roulette == null && b.roulette != null` or `(a.roulette != null ? a.roulette : -Infinity) < b.roulette` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to keep on breaking ties if one parameter is same.

```
 obj.sort(function(a, b) {
    var rouletteDiff = compare(a.roulette, b.roulette);
    if(rouletteDiff != 0) return rouletteDiff;
    var noveltyDiff = compare(a.novelty, b.novelty);
    if(noveltyDiff != 0) return noveltyDiff;
    return compare(a.popularity, b.popularity);
  });

  function compare(x,y){
    if(x == undefined) return 1;
    if(y == undefined) return -1;
    if(x === y){
        return 0;
    }else{
        return x > y ? -1 : 1
    }
  }
```